Godot 4.3 Bug with TileSet putting diagonals tiles with autotiles
I'm trying to put tilesets on a tilemap using autotiling, and I have configured the terrain using the following schema:

But it's not working as it's suppose to, for example, the diagonal

It was suppose to put the following tiles as the "floor", from left to right:
  
But instead, it putted the following:
  
Even if I have tiles on corners, and have selected to match corners and sides.
